# import Hbase to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to move data from Hbase to Hive . Below is my code

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_hive(key string, firstname string, age string)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “id:firstname,id:age")
TBLPROPERTIES(“hbase.table.name” = “hl”);
```

but i am getting bellow error

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:10 mismatched input 'org' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table file format specification
```

I don't know what i am missing here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the single quotes near `STORED BY`. it is different.

same for double quotes on the next line

If you want to give Hive access to an existing HBase table, use `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. But i cant see my hbase data in hive table.

Comment: try WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “:key,id:firstname,id:age")

Comment: when you created the table with EXTERNAL TABLE, does the output showed OK? can you scan hl in hbase prompt and check data available

Comment: yes it showed `ok` , and i scanned the `hl` data it is shwoing me 851 records.

Comment: can you print single row

Comment: i fixed my problem. i added wrong name in `SERDEPROPERTIES` for my coloumns.